# "Import Files into iTunes" automator action not working

Tags: itunes, macos, automator

I'm having an issue with a simple automator action, "Import Files into iTunes". It's the only thing I have in the workflow but when I drop audio files onto the application, the action encounters an error. In trying to figure out what was amiss, I read that there was a version number conflict after iTunes 10, so I followed the instructions [here](http://www.cnet.com/news/itunes-automator-workflows-no-longer-working-after-itunes-10/) but they did not fix the issue. Does anyone have a suggestion on what to try or how to diagnose the issue? I'm running Yosemite (10.10.2) and iTunes 12.1.0.50. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Did you know about the "~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes" folder?  Anything you copy to this folder will automatically be added to iTunes.  Have you tried adding content this way?

Comment: I didn't know about that, but the useful thing about the automator action is that it allows you important the files and simultaneously add them to a specified playlist.